# Redirecting to plugin page instead of index/profile page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a user role in wordpress and for this role I have to redirect this user to a plugin page directly and hide all menus ( dashboard and profile page also hidden ) and show only a page from plugin only.
I also don't want to create any new folder or page in wp-admin folder it should remains as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a filter that can check the user's role immediately after they log in and change the redirect location. The filter you want is `login_redirect`, and the [WordPress Codex page for login_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) has a pretty good example of what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick reply. I have checked your suggestion and it works great. but before your reply i make some code for getting output and it also works but it may be wrong style of coding. Please tell me is my code is proper or not : 
First I check the role of user
Then hide all the menus using below code:


$restricted = array(__('Dashboard'),__('Profile'));
  while (prev($menu))
  {
   $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
   if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
  }


and then redirect page through javascript.

Comment: In general I would avoid using Javascript for a redirect like this if there's another way to go. There's no guarantee the Javascript will execute properly (or at all) on the client, which would leave them on the page you don't want them to see!